# Spreadsheet don't works in ocra package

Tags: ruby, windows, exe, spreadsheet

I have an ruby app, witch using spreadsheet. After packaging app into EXE by ocra I have an error:

**"incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-1251"**

on reading ANY xls file...

```
Windows 7 x86
Ruby 1.9.3p0 (by RubyInstaller)
spreadsheet-0.6.8
ocra-1.3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved a problem.

While packing my script into EXE, ocra runs it.

But my script without arguments does nothing...

I just wrote: Spreadsheet.open('MyDoc.xls')